# what is the reason for the Change in DFT analysis after downsampling

Tags: dft

firstly the original signal's dft analysis is this the signal is sammpled at 1000Hz
[image]

the signal is then downsampled under different rates such as 25Hz

this is the dft analysis of the signal downsampled under 25Hz
[image]

what is the reason for this phenomenon?

Comment: For which phenomenon?

Comment: the change in DFT analysis

Answer (score 2):

Because you have resampled the signal to a sample rate below twice the highest frequency in the signal, you are seeing the signal plus an aliased image of the signal both summed together.  Two partially overlapped rectangles will sum to produce the "head-and-shoulders" shape you see in the aliased spectrum.

Comment: in this case would the nyquist frequency be 12.5 Hz and would the frequencies present in the signal be 5 to 12.5 Hz ?

Comment: Signal seems to be 5 to  15 Hz.  It's summed with its complex conjugate at -5 to -15 Hz which you see as 10 to 20 Hz because the sample rate is too low.

Comment: i do apologize i am afraid i don't understand what you mean